# PHP: Email scraping from a list of urls listed in a txt file

Tags: php, web-scraping

I am trying to extract emails from urls listed in a txt file.

But only the last url of the txt file displays his related emails.

The output appears like this :

*url1*

*url2*

*url3*

*url4*

email: *email address1*

email: *email address2*

I do not understand what I am doing wrong.

Is there something obvious that I am missing ? Thank you for your help.

The code :

```
<?php
$handle = fopen("url-list.txt", "r");
if ($handle) {
    while (($url = fgets($handle)) !== false) {
        // process the line read.
        echo "<br>";
        echo $url ;
        echo "<br>";
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 20);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 5);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    $emails = extract_emails_from($result);
    
    foreach(array_unique($emails) as $email) {
        echo "email: ", trim($email);
        echo "<br>";
    }
}
fclose($handle);
} else {
    // error opening the file.
} 
function extract_emails_from($string) {
    preg_match_all("/[\._a-zA-Z0-9-]+@[\._a-zA-Z0-9-]+/i", $string, $matches);
    return $matches[0];
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a scope issue.

```
$emails = extract_emails_from($result);
```

The `$emails` variable gets rewritten in every iteration of the `while` loop.

**Solution:**

Create a new array outside of the loop and merge the results into it.

```
$allEmails = [];

while (($url = fgets($handle)) !== false) {
   // ... rest of your code
   $emails = extract_emails_from($result);
   $allEmails = array_merge($allEmails, $emails);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried the way you have advised but the issue stays the same. In my code, am I not echoing $email et each iteration, before it gets rewritten ? I might be wrong but I thought the foreach loop did it, no ?

Comment: The `$emails` only contain the current iteration results. If you want to print out all results, you need to print (or iterate through) `$allEmails` (instead of the `$emails` in your current loop).